# How do I pass variables between Ruby classes?

Tags: ruby, variables

I'm creating a card game with multiple classes. Currently, I'm using global variables to hold the `$shuffled_deck`, `$players_hand`, and `$dealers_hand` variables, but I worry when using global variables (perhaps, needlessly) and would prefer to use instance variables.

I've been reading around, but nothing is really clicking. Can anyone help point me in the right direction with this?

Using instance variables I haven't been able to save the `@players_hand` and `@dealers_hand` to be able to use them in other classes. For instance, I have `@players_hand` from the `Player` class. I have the `Dealer` class draw a card, but I can't pull that `@players_hand` into the `Dealer` class to add the two together.

My current code is:

```
class Blackjack

  def initialize
    @player = Player.new
    @dealer = Dealer.new
  end
end

class Dealer

  def initialize
    @deck = Deck.new
    $dealers_hand = 0
  end

  def hit_dealer
    @deck.hit_dealer
  end

  def hit_player
    @deck.hit_player
  end

  def draw_card
    @hit = $shuffled_deck
  end

  def shuffle
    @deck.suits
  end
end

class Player

  def initialize
    $players_hand = 0
  end   
end

class Deck

 def suits
   #code that shuffled the deck..
   $shuffled_deck = @shuffled_deck
 end

 def hit_player
   @hit = $shuffled_deck.pop
 end

 def hit_dealer
   @hit = $shuffled_deck.pop
 end

end
```

Comment: Good question, but there will be quite a lot of concepts to go through to get a complete answer. Hopefully someone will know a good reference document, but you'll definitely need to get a handle on **encapsulation** which is the idea of working out which object a piece of data *belongs* to, and normally ends up with you adding more (smaller) classes with more specific responsibilities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, or `attr_accessor`. Here's how they work:

- `attr_reader :players_hand`: Allows you to write `some_player.players_hand` to get the value of that player's `players_hand` instance variable
- `attr_writer :players_hand`: Allows you to write `some_player.players_hand = 0` to set the variable to 0
- `attr_accessor :players_hand`: Allows you to both read and write, as though you'd used both `attr_reader` and `attr_writer`.

Incidentally, all these do is write methods for you. If you wanted, you could do it manually like this:

```
class Player
  def initialize
    @players_hand = 0
  end  

  def players_hand
    @players_hand
  end

  def players_hand=(new_value)
    @players_hand = new_value
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Chuck, so I would want to do something like. 
`class Player
  attr_accessor :players_hand
  #rest of players methods
end`
`def Blackjack
  def initialize
    @player = Player.new
  end
end`
and then write to that players hand ... `@player.players_hand`

Answer (score 6):

using your example you can do it like this

```
class Blackjack
  attr_reader :player, :dealer

  def initialize
    @player = Player.new
    @dealer = Dealer.new
  end
end

class Dealer
  def dealers_hand #the long java way of a getter
    @dealers_hand
  end

  #and now the short ruby way
  attr_reader :dealers_hand #if you only need to read the attribute
  attr_writer :dealers_hand #if you only need to write the attribute
  attr_accessor: dealers_hand #if you need both

  def initialize
    @deck = Deck.new
    @dealers_hand = 5
  end

  def hit_dealer
    @deck.hit_dealer
  end

  def hit_player
    @deck.hit_player
  end

  def draw_card
    @hit = $shuffled_deck
  end

  def shuffle
    @deck.suits
  end
end

class Player
  attr_reader :players_hand
  def initialize
    @players_hand = 0
  end   
end

class Deck

 def suits
   attr_reader :shuffled_deck
   @shuffled_deck = @shuffled_deck
 end

 def hit_player
   @hit = $shuffled_deck.pop
 end

 def hit_dealer
   @hit = $shuffled_deck.pop
 end

end

game = Blackjack.new
p game.dealer.dealers_hand
game.dealer.dealers_hand = 4
p game.dealer.dealers_hand
```

Comment: would it be better to use `attr_accessor :players_hand` in the Dealer class instead of both `attr_writer` and `attr_reader`?

Comment: of course, you are right, should haven mentioned that, edited the class Dealer with some explanation